# nsIGenericFactory.h is missing in the above version of xulrunner-2.0.en-US.win32.sdk

Tags: mozilla, xpcom, xulrunner

Previously, I created **XPCOM dll** for the **mozilla version 3.6 and XulRunner version of 1.9.2**.

Now I try to update that xpcom dll for the mozilla recent versions namely 4 and above.

So I downloaded Xul Runner above version but I couldn't find **nsIGenericFactory.h**.

How to work my xpcom dll for the mozilla 4 and above versions.

Actually I used the following sample to develop XPCOM DLL.

http://www.iosart.com/firefox/xpcom/

Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Mozilla 4.0 is using Gecko 2.0 this applys to your situation:

*Quoting the* [XPCOM changes in Gecko 2.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0):

> Note that nsIGenericFactory.h has been removed.
>   References to nsIGenericFactory.h should be replaced with mozilla/ModuleUtils.h

After doing so, you would have to recompile all XPCOM components following the instructions from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0

There is a topic about this problem in the [mozilla forum](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1378) too.

The headerfile is provided on this site: [nsIGenericFactory.h](http://xulrunner-1.9.2.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.9.2.2plus-pnobinonly/nsIGenericFactory_8h-source.html)

Comment: @ Fuzzy: previously, I compile this link http://www.iosart.com/firefox/xpcom/ with the help of gecko-sdk-1.9. Now I migrate to Gecko-sdk-2 or above. I changed the header file nsIgenericFactory.h  into mozilla/ModuleUtils.h but the application is not compiling properly.How to run this sample with the help of new gecko-sdk-2 or above?

Comment: @ Fuzzy: for time being, I accepted your answer. Please try the above the link and give some suggestions.

Comment: @karthik: Did you try out the suggestions posted as comments on http://www.iosart.com/firefox/xpcom/? What does "not compiling properly" mean in your case? Errors? Referring to [this topic in the forums](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?p=8900&sid=5ad316dc442eed775ef208b8cc56888f): `The only changes that you need to do is to declare it in chrome.manifest and recompile it for the 2.0 SDK`

Comment: Fuzzy, I copied xpt file and put it under components folder and referred it from chrome.manifest. Still i am getting Link error like the following:                                                        xpcomglue_s.lib(GenericFactory.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__moz_xmalloc Could you please help us What I need to do to resolve those link errors

Comment: [This link](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/zOxEyIVzkcnAm06VMF9A) might help you. Since I'm not able to try this right now, I can only recommend the first results on a google search with your error. Sorry 'bout that!